# Give examples for these strict inclusions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\text{int}(A),\text{cl}(A),\text{bd}(A)$ denote the interior, closure, and boundary of $A$. For the following statements, give examples to show the inclusion can be strict:

1. $A \subseteq \text{int}(\text{cl}(A))$ where A is open
2. $\text{cl}(\text{int}(A)) \subseteq A$ where A is closed
3. $\text{bd}(\text{bd}(A)) \subseteq bd(A)$

I can prove these statements, but I don't know how to find the examples.

Also, let K be a non-empty compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f:K \rightarrow K$ be a function which has the following property:
$$\|f(\vec{x})-f(\vec{y})\|<\|\vec{x}-\vec{y}\| \ \forall \vec{x},\vec{y} \in K \text{ such that } \vec{x} \neq \vec{y}.$$ Give an example to show that $f$ may not be strict contraction on a closed subset $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: 1 is false (A closed ball). 2 too (A open ball)

Comment: 1and 2 are false,  How did you prove them !  for 3, take $A=Q$ rational number.

Comment: forgot to add restriction on A for 1 and 2, sorry. just edited.

Answer (score 0):

Think about $x^2$ for the mapping. This gives you an example when $n = 1$ for the right choice of $K$. You can use this to build an answer for arbitrary $n$.